# Mat-spinner is working for some components but not working for some other components in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use mat-spinner in a project. Surprisingly, while the mat-spinner is working for some components, it is not working for some others. What could be the problem? I've used the following code in component.ts file for which component the mat-spinner is not working-

```
        loading: boolean
        constructor( private router: Router){
        router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                 this.loading = true;
            }
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationError || event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
                 this.loading = false;
            }
        });
     }
```

and the following code segment in component.html file

```
 <mat-spinner *ngIf="loading"></mat-spinner>
```

The spinner is not showing even if the **loading** variable is returning true . My app.module.ts file is the following

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatDatepickerModule, 
MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, 
MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatSelectModule, MatSortModule,
 MatStepperModule, MatTableModule, } from '@angular/material';

import { MatMomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        DataTablesModule,
        BrowserModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        NgxMatDatetimePickerModule,
        NgxMatTimepickerModule,
        NgxMatMomentModule,
        NgxMatNativeDateModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatNativeDatetimeModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatListModule
})
```

What can I do now?

Comment: The component where it is not working, is it declared inside another module?

Comment: @shaktimaan No.

Answer (score 1):

I think the change detection does not have time to detect changes for `loading` on some cases.

I would switch `loading` to an Observable and handle manually how it is shown.

```js
loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.router.events.pipe(
    map(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        return true;
      }
      if (
        event instanceof NavigationEnd ||
        event instanceof NavigationError ||
        event instanceof NavigationCancel
      ) {
        return false;
      }
      return undefined;
    }),
    filter(ev => ev !== undefined),
    switchMap(loading => {
      if (!loading) {
        return of(loading).pipe(delay(1000));
      } else {
        return of(loading);
      }
    })
  );
```

See [this reproduction on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-67145965).

Then use the async pipe to unwrap it in your template.

For more advanced state management of the loader, I recommend this article form Angular GDE Alexander Inkin : [RxJS Challenge #17: Non-flicker loader](https://medium.com/angularwave/rxjs-challenge-17-non-flicker-loader-15545d3be525)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any error in the console, then probably, `mat-spinner` is available. The reason for it not coming up might be the way loading is handled. I'd suggest moving this to a central service so that it runs for each component.

One additional pointer: Since your components(probably are in the same module), there is no actual waiting time between route navigation. You should also look into applications business needs to show the loader.